# Как в текущем элементе заменить текст с помощью Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть мини-карточка товара на главной, хочу добавить выбор для быстрого заказа, сколько штук заказать. 
Делаю это следующим образом:

```
        $('.count-goods').hide();
    $('.counting').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.count-goods').show();
    });
    $('.count-goods span').click(function(){
        var text, text_rep;

        text = $(this).text();
        text_rep = $('.counting').text();

        $('.counting').parent('.btn-count').text(text);
        $(this).text(text_rep);
    });
```

Я начинающий, и поэтому код очень примитивный. Собственно, по клику по первому я открываю окошко с выбором элементов, которое до этого скрыл, и далее хочу, чтобы при нажатии на элемент этого окошка текст менялся местами с главным окошком. То есть изначально стоит 1, я кликаю на единичку, и выдвигается окошко с выбором 2, 3, 4. При клике на 3 оно идет на место 1, а 1 идет на место 3.

Но я что-то не могу понять, как вытащить именно это окошко. Мой код не работает. :(

Вот мой HTML-код карточки:

```
                <figure>
                <img src="images/1.png"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <span class="special">СПЕЦИАЛЬНОЕ<br />ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ</span>
                    <span class="new">NEW</span>
                    <span class="color"><span class="w"></span>Выбрать<br /> цвет</span>
                    <span class="color_select"><span class="w"></span><span class="grey"></span><span class="blue"></span></span>

                    <a href="#" class="title">Свинг-машина (массажер раскачивающийся) DS-098</a>
                    <div class="price"><b>690 руб.</b> <del>790 руб.</del></div>
                    <span class="btn btn-count counting">1</span>
                    <div class="btn-group count-goods">
                        <span class="btn btn-count">2</span>
                        <span class="btn btn-count">3</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="btn btn-buy">Купить</span>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-buy-big">
                        <a href="#" class="btn">В кредит <span>600 руб./мес</span></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Купить в 1 клик</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Добавить в корзину</a>
                    </div>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
```

Таких карточек более 8 на странице, и необходимо, чтобы все действо происходило именно в карточке, где произошли клики.

Прошу помощи, буду очень вам признателен.

Comment: Из вашего объяснения возникает мысль, что вам нужно вот это: http://jsfiddle.net/17bz6jh0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('.count-goods').hide();
$('.counting').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.count-goods').show();
});
$('.count-goods span').click(function(){
    var text, text_rep, cardCounting = $(this).parents('figcaption').find('.counting');

    text = $(this).text();
    text_rep = cardCounting.text();
    cardCounting.text(text)
    $(this).text(text_rep);
});
```

Это должно сработать, но с сортировкой по возрастанию надо бы поработать еще, а то как-то не очень получается http://jsfiddle.net/17bz6jh0/